# How do you import the sample Oracle HR database into SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

EDIT: I think I'm close to solving this now. i will self-answer if so

I've been stuck on this for a while now - I want to use the sample Oracle Human Resources database. I've been studying through [these instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm) to no avail.

So I have downloaded both Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, along with SQL Developer. And I can play with it and create a sample database. But I don't know how to use the HR database.

any tips appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news - I finally figured it out. I had to go into SQL Command Line, and then put in these commands( [from this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#BJFDGBHJ)) :

Type: connect

Enter user-name: system

Enter password:

Then, we need to unlock the HR :

```
SQL> ALTER USER hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Then we make a password for this user :

```
SQL> ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY <hr-password>;
```

So after this, I could access it from SQL Develloper. thanks